# List all tasks running in a specific directory and sub-directories and kill them windows

Tags: python, powershell, batch-file, cmd, process

Given a specific directory in Windows,

How can I list all active running tasks by the current user in that directory and all of it's sub-directories and then proceed to kill all those tasks one by one?
That includes any running .exe application, opened cmds ..etc (pretty much anything that could prevent deleting the folder due to a running task in the directory

Preferably through python , powershell or batch

Comment: Processes or tasks don't run in a specific file system directory. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I mean applications running in any folder and it's sub-folders. The exact use case is that I need to execute a script in a specific folder to terminate any running application in this folder or it's sub-folders. So that If I try to delete this folder I don't get errors about there is a running process in this directory

Comment: You must know the directory structure and all files in it which could possibly be in use. Please stop trying to ask generic XY type problems and be more specific. Also asking for solutions in multiple scripting languages shows that you've not even decided a root to solving your own issue before posting. Your question, until you've defined a language, and at least researched and tried something is too broad for this platform.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Process` displays the **Path** of where the executable lives. This alone should get you a good start seeing as the only other step missing is the user to look under. Fortunately, `Get-Process` also has a `-IncludeUserName` switch which (*as the name indicates*) includes the owner of the process; *the use of this parameter requires an elevated user permission*. That said, a filter for both should be all you need.

```
$path = 'C:\Program Files' # directory path
$user = $env:USERNAME # User to check under
Get-Process -IncludeUserName | 
    Where-Object -FilterScript {
        $_.UserName -like "*$user" -and $_.Path -like "$path*"
    }
```

If you're looking to delete the contents of the entire folder in `$path`, this assumes that you're searching for all running process coming from that folder, but only if it's being ran by the person listed in `$user`. What this doesn't account for is unreleased handles that need to be closed prior to stopping each process.

In order to stop the process(es) just pipe to `Stop-Process`.